# Why HKD-USD conversion rate has been so stable for years?

Tags: currency, foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar

I reviewed the HKD-USD exchange rate and found it quite stable for years no matter what "big events" happened.

Why so?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article explaining this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_exchange_rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make it an Answer: Because the exchange rate has been "pegged" to a specific value since 1983 by the Hong Kong government, rather than being allowed to drift freely.

"In 1972, the Hong Kong dollar was pegged to the U.S. dollar at a rate of 5.65 H.K. dollar = 1 U.S. dollar. This was revised to 5.085 H.K. dollar = 1 U.S. dollar in 1973. Between 1974 and 1983, the Hong Kong dollar was floated. On 17 October 1983, the currency was pegged at a rate of 7.8 H.K. dollar = 1 U.S. dollar, through the currency board system."

-- Wikipedia article on [Hong Kong dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_dollar).

The Wikipedia article [Linked Exchange Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_exchange_rate) provides some additional detail about how this is managed, and notes that in practice some minor variation will occur.